# Debugging Clang-generated RTTI code with GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, clang

I'm using Clang++ together with GDB. I've noticed that for some polymorphic classes GDB does not shows correct dynamic type.  After some investigation it turned out that Clang puts different typenames in DWARF and RTTI :

I have a template class:

```
template< class T, sc_writer_policy POL>
class sc_signal : public sc_object {/*...*/}
```

where sc_writer_policy is an enum:

```
enum sc_writer_policy
{
  SC_ONE_WRITER        = 0, 
  SC_MANY_WRITERS      = 1, 
  SC_UNCHECKED_WRITERS = 3
};
```

When I debug polymorphic objects of this class I got GDB errors like this:

```
warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'sc_core::sc_signal<int, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0>'
```

It looks like that the source of the problem is that it type name seems to be saved differently in RTTI and Debug info.

From GDB:

```
(gdb) info types sc_signal<int
All types matching regular expression "sc_signal<int":
sc_core::sc_signal<int, sc_core::SC_ONE_WRITER>
```

Using RTTI:

```
cout << typeid(*obj).name();
N7sc_core9sc_signalIiLNS_16sc_writer_policyE0EEE
```

So in RTTI we have mangled

```
sc_core::sc_signal<int, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0>
```

Is it possible to make Clang emitting same type-name in both cases so it can be debugged in GDB? Or is it possible to make GDB understand that

```
sc_core::sc_signal<int, sc_core::SC_ONE_WRITER> 
sc_core::sc_signal<int, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0>
```

are the same types?

Complete code sample:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

namespace sc_core
{

enum sc_writer_policy
{
    SC_ONE_WRITER        = 0,
    SC_MANY_WRITERS      = 1,
    SC_UNCHECKED_WRITERS = 3
};

class sc_object {
public:
    virtual ~sc_object(){}
};

template< class T, sc_writer_policy POL = SC_ONE_WRITER>
class sc_signal : public sc_object {
    T dummy_field = 42;
};

}

int main() {
    sc_core::sc_object *obj = new sc_core::sc_signal<int>();
    std::cout << typeid(obj).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Testing in GDB when compiled with g++ 7.0:

```
(gdb) p *obj
$2 = (sc_core::sc_signal<int, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0>) {<sc_core::sc_object> = {_vptr.sc_object = 0x400c78 <vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<int, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0>+16>}, dummy_field = 42}
```

Testing in GDB when compiled with Clang 5.0:

```
(gdb) p *obj
warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'sc_core::sc_signal<int, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0>'
$1 = warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'sc_core::sc_signal<int, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0>'
warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'sc_core::sc_signal<int, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0>'
{_vptr$sc_object = 0x400df0 <vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<int, (sc_core::sc_writer_policy)0>+16>}
```